# Select all orders except the max order for each distinct customer

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the poor formatting but as part of a larger problem, I have created a query that produces this table:

```
id id2    
4  7    
4  6    
1  3    
1  2    
1  1
```

How would I extract the rows that don't have the highest id2 for each id1.

What I want:

```
id id2    
4  6    
1  2    
1  1
```

I can only seem to figure out how to get rid of the max `id2` overall but not for each distinct id1. Any help on actually differentiating the max `id2` for each `id1` would be appreciated.

Comment: What if an `id1` only has one `id2` value?

Comment: Than it will output the row with that id2 value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below way -

```
select a.id, a.id2 
from tablename a
where a.id2 <> (select max(a1.id2) from tablename a1 where a.id=a1.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `RANK()` provides one option:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, id2, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id2 DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, id2
FROM cte
WHERE rnk > 1
ORDER BY id DESC, id2 DESC;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

instead of a correlated subquery in the where, you can LEFT JOIN and apply not in...

```
select id, id2 
   from yourTable YT
      LEFT JOIN 
      ( select id, max( id2 ) highestID2
           from YourTable 
           group by id ) TopPerID
         on YT.ID = TopPerID.ID
         AND YT.ID2 != TopPerID.highestID2
   where TopPerID.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can have `id` values with only one `id2` value, you need to check for that situation as well, which you can do by comparing the `MAX(id2)` value with the `MIN(id2)` value in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(id2) AS max_id2, MIN(id2) AS min_id2
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY id) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id 
                     AND (t1.id2 < t2.max_id2 OR t2.min_id2 = t2.max_id2)
```

If we add a row `2, 5` to your sample data this correctly gives the result as

```
id  id2
4   6
1   2
1   1
2   5
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/208354/3)